# Browse available DLL functions and run them interactively

Tags: windows

I've found [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) that allows me to list available functions in a DLL, now I need to run one of them. Actually, I am trying to get the library version this way, since there is no metadata, therefore the function probably doesn't have parameters. I know I can write a program to do that, but does anybody know a utility with which it can be done fast and easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the easiest way to do this is with python:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> dll = cdll.LoadLibrary("libmylib.dll")
>>> c_char_p(dll.mylib_version_str())
c_char_p(b'1.1.6')
```

Where `mylib_version_str` is the function name that was found using [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html).